# Run docker as not sudoers

Tags: permissions, docker

I have on my ubuntu instance a group of non-sudoers ("deploy" group). In order, to enable them to use docker I have to change the permission of "/var/run/docker.sock" file to `chgrp deploy /var/run/docker.sock` and `chmod 770 /var/run/docker.sock`.

Is this approach considered as security blunder, is there any other better approach?

Comment: You might be interested in a container engine that allows to run rootless containers, such as [Podman](https://podman.io/). This way users can start containers without having either `sudo` rights or having a wildly opened docker socket which is not a good idea as described by @vidarlo.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at `/var/run/docker.sock`, you'll see that it's owned by `root` UID, and `docker` gid.

```
# ls -la /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jun  2 11:37 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Changing group ownership to your own group may stop docker from working properly, as it relies on the `docker` group for other functions.

The proper way to handle this is to add your users to the `docker` group. This is [detailed in the post-install documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/). Note that giving a user access to docker is more or less equivalent with making that user root. If you have docker access, becoming root [is extremely trivial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface):

> First of all, only trusted users should be allowed to control your Docker daemon. This is a direct consequence of some powerful Docker features. Specifically, Docker allows you to share a directory between the Docker host and a guest container; and it allows you to do so without limiting the access rights of the container. This means that you can start a container where the /host directory is the / directory on your host; and the container can alter your host filesystem without any restriction.